# How can I calculate the standard deviation when knowing the P10, P25, P75, P90, mean and median?

Tags: standard-deviation, quantiles

I'm trying to find the standard deviation from some simulated task duration results. The results provided the following:

Mean - 430

Median - 374

P10 - 371.8

P25 - 372.4

P75 - 440.5

P90 - 588.6

From my understanding, since the mean and median are different I cannot assume a normal distribution (so I can't divide the IQR by 1.349 to calculate the standard deviation). How else can I calculate it? Can I get away with dividing IQR by 1.349?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just get the program that calculated those numbers to give you the SD as well?

Comment: The above-linked question seems to contain a lot of relevant info; if the mean is far from the median that would suggest that the standard deviation isn't a good summary measure for your data either..

Comment: How many points do you have? If you only have a few, you can't tell if the underlying distribution is normal or not.

Comment: I am downvoting because the question provides no information about how the standard deviation will be used, and because there clearly is not enough information for a good estimate. As an example of the difficulties, truncating the trails symmetrically about the mean might preserve all the given data but reduce the standard deviation significantly.

Comment: Different distributions might have the same mean, median, quartiles and extreme deciles and yet have very different standard deviations, so you can't just *calculate* a standard deviation. If you make some distributional assumption, then you may be able to calculate an estimate of a population standard deviation. Or you could give a lower bound on a sample standard deviation.

Answer (score 3):

The example below shows that these values do not have to uniquely define the standard deviation.

```r
set.seed(2024)
N <- 1000
x <- y <- sort(rexp(N, 1))
s <- 1000
y[1] <- y[1] - s
y[N] <- y[N] + s
mean(x) == mean(y)
median(x) == median(y)
quantile(x, 0.1) == quantile(y, 0.1)
quantile(x, 0.25) == quantile(y, 0.25)
quantile(x, 0.75) == quantile(y, 0.75)
quantile(x, 0.9) == quantile(y, 0.9)
sd(x) == sd(y)
```

Here, the means, medians, and specified quantiles are equal. However, the standard deviations are quite different.

I constructed this example by giving two data sets that differ in just their smallest and largest values, which are shifted by the same amount in different directions, preserving the specified quantities but resulting in wildly different standard deviations when that shift value `s` is as large as I set it.